# iOS - SOAP based Payment APIs usage in Native Application

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

We have a third party SOAP based Payment processing API exposed for us.

We want to use the exposed APIs in our Native iPhone APP to process a purchase.

So we will be having a view(UIView) where we collect Credit card number, CVV and card expiry information and pass it to the APIs to process the payment.

> We don't want to use in-app purchases.

We are aware that the same can be achieved by running it in embedded web view (Safari).

Is this allowed in according to the "APPLE RULES" ?

Kindly Advice

Answer (score 1):

Your app will probably be rejected due to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected.

However using another payment technology as IAP can be used/is required when selling physical goods or services:

> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected

Comment: The OP did not mention what kind of goods he intends to sell. If they were physical goods (like a car), then his approach would be perfectly valid and fine.

Comment: @Till That's true. I expanded the answer accordingly.